# How to call a string value into sql query in python

Tags: python, mysql, sql

I am trying to call a string value from a container tn (input given by user) to complete a sql query

```
# lists is a list in which all table names in the database is stored
ct=0
while ct!=2:
    print("1.Enter the table name you want access")
    print("2.Exit")
    ct=int(input("Enter your choice (1 or 2) :"))
    if ct==1:
        tn=input("Enter table name :")
        break
    elif ct==2:
        sys.exit(0)
    else:
        print("INVALID INPUT")
if tn in lists:
    print()
    print("Table found!")
    mycursor.execute("SELECT * FROM (%s)",(tn,))
for i in mycursor:
    print(i)
```

i want that sql query becomes complete it executes and show me the results back (that is the table should be displayed which the user have input)

i get this error message when running the code:-

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\11c1.System2-PC\Desktop\MYSQL\Mysql (Software).py", line 59, in <module>
    mycursor.execute("SELECT * FROM (%s)",(tn,))
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\cursor.py", line 551, in execute
    self._handle_result(self._connection.cmd_query(stmt))
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\connection.py", line 490, in cmd_query
    result = self._handle_result(self._send_cmd(ServerCmd.QUERY, query))
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\connection.py", line 395, in _handle_result
    raise errors.get_exception(packet)
mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''11c')' at line 1
```

assuming that '11c' is the input given by the user and a table by name 11c really exists in the database

When i tried the same code with `?` like :-

```
ct=0
while ct!=2:
    print("1.Enter the table name you want access")
    print("2.Exit")
    ct=int(input("Enter your choice (1 or 2) :"))
    if ct==1:
        tn=input("Enter table name :")
        break
    elif ct==2:
        sys.exit(0)
    else:
        print("INVALID INPUT")
if tn in lists:
    print()
    print("Table found!")
    mycursor.execute("SELECT * FROM (?)",(tn,))
for i in mycursor:
    print(i)
```

this gives the error as:-

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\11c1.System2-PC\Desktop\MYSQL\Mysql (Software).py", line 59, in <module>
    mycursor.execute("SELECT * FROM (?)",(tn,))
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\cursor.py", line 543, in execute
    "Not all parameters were used in the SQL statement")
mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: Not all parameters were used in the SQL statement
```

Comment: You don't need parentheses in query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below query syntex:

```
query= "SELECT * FROM %s"
mycursor.execute(query%(tn,))
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: @skannet, try `mycursor.execute(query, tn)`.

Comment: @OlvinRoght nope same error mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '%s' at line 1

Comment: @skannet, what is in `tn`, just string name of table?

Comment: @OlvinRoght ```tn``` is the table name which user will input and its datatype will be string

Comment: @skannet, have you tried to use debugger and check content of `tn` before function call?

Comment: @OlvinRoght i have checked the content of ```tn``` it is the exact value given by user and yes it is the name of the table in the database ```Enter table name :11c

Table access gained!
11c  # output generated by print(tn)```

Comment: @skannet try the edited one solution above! it should work.